# Splitting dictionary of lists based on criteria in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have data from travel diaries which has been read in from a csv file. I have it set up as a dictionary with a bunch of lists. E.g.:

```
print diary['ID'][1] gives 123456789
print diary['TravelReferenceDay'][1] gives 1 for a Monday
```

I want to randomnly select an ID from the array based on the day e.g.:

```
random.choice(diary['ID']) if diary['TravelReferenceDay'] == 1
```

I can arrange the data by TravelReferenceDay in the csv file. I had tried the groupby method to split up the array:

```
groups = []
uniquekeys = []
for k, g in groupby(diary, diary['TravelReferenceDay']):
    groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
    uniquekeys.append(k)
```

But that gave the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Could you suggest a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is your data stored in parallel arrays?  That's not going to be easy to work with.

Comment: Yes, should I have a list of dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution with a list comprehensions:

```
In [1]: import random
   ...: diary = {'ID': ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55'], 'TravelReferenceDay': [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]}
   ...: monday_diary = [x for n, x in enumerate(diary['ID']) if diary['TravelReferenceDay'][n] == 1]

In [2]: monday_diary
Out[2]: ['11', '22', '55']

In [3]: random.choice(monday_diary)
Out[3]: '22'
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `groupby` is a callable that is invoked on successive items from the iterable first argument.

You want to use `operator.itemgetter('TravelReferenceDay')`:

```
for k, g in groupby(diary, operator.itemgetter('TravelReferenceDay')):
    ...
```

This is equivalent to `lambda x: x['TravelReferenceDay']`.

Note that `groupby` expects the iterable to already be sorted by the key; groups contain *adjacent* items with the same key.

OK, this won't work because you've stored your data as parallel arrays.  For ease of processing I'd advise to convert it to a list of dicts:

```
diary = [dict((k, diary[k][i]) for k in diary) for i in range(len(diary['ID']))]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm now getting the error that "string indices must be integers, not str" on the "for k,g..." line.

Comment: Yes, your data structures are a bit odd.  See comment above.